# Can tensorflow use matrix of matrix?

Tags: tensorflow

I know tensorflow can calculate expressions like `[ [a,b,c] ] x [ [x],[y],[z] ]` when the elements are primitive data type (integer or float). 
Is it possible to perform a similar computation when each of `a`, `b` and `c` is a 1x3 matrix and `x`, `y` and `z` are 3x1 matrices?

Can TensorFlow calculate and optimize this formula?

Answer (score 0):

The [`tf.batch_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#batch_matmul) operator can perform matrix multiplications on batches of matrices. In this case, you would have a tensor `abc` of shape `(3, 1, 3)` (where `abc[0, :, :] = a`, `abc[1, :, :] = b`, etc.) and a tensor `xyz` of shape `(3, 3, 1)` (where `xyz[0, :, :] = x`, etc.).

```
abc = ...
xyz = ...

result = tf.batch_matmul(abc, xyz)

print result.get_shape()  # ==> "(3, 1, 1)"
```

`result` is a 3-D tensor with contents equivalent to  `tf.pack([tf.matmul(a, x), tf.matmul(b, y), tf.matmul(c, z)])`.